Phoenix / Elixir: Sending email via Gmail certificate error
I suspect it's some kind of certificate issue.
I'm running an Ubuntu server.
My Elixir / Phoenix code:
        case Mailer.deliver(email) do
          {:ok, _response} ->
            IO.puts("Email sent successfully.")
          {:error, reason} ->
            IO.puts("Failed to send email.")
            IO.puts("Reason: #{inspect(reason)}")
        end 

The error I get in production:
Failed to send email.
Reason: {:retries_exceeded, {:network_failure, ~c"142.250.141.109", {:error, {:options, :incompatible, [verify: :verify_peer, cacerts: :undefined]}}}}

And here's the relevant section of my config/prod.ex:
config :my_app, MyApp.Mailer,
  adapter: Swoosh.Adapters.SMTP,
  relay: "smtp.gmail.com",
  username: "myemail@gmail.com",
  password: "abcd 1234 abcd 1234",
  ssl: true,
  tls: :always,
  auth: :always,
  port: 465,
  retries: 1


I did try:
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates

But no luck.
The complaint seems to be Elixir not being able to use Gmail's SSL certificate, is my understanding correct?

I've seen a handful of weird SSL errors that sometimes have to do with the host OS having an out-of-date or misconfigured openssl library.  Sometimes you can correct for this by passing specific options in code; other times libraries and/or packages need to be updated.  I'm not sure if this applies to your error, but it might be relevant.

I did not try but, because of the cacerts: :undefined, it seems you miss a:
cacerts: :public_key.cacerts_get(),

See details in this bug report.

Thanks for the comment. No luck, I will updated the question to add this in.

Your tip, plus a few other things got it working in the end! See my answer on:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79025581/simply-sending-email-with-elixir-phoenix-via-amazon-ses-but-cacerts-undefined/
